# How to reverse a list containing elements as strings starting with uppercase letter followed by lowercase letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  list3=list2.extend(list1.reverse())
  return list3


Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]                     
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

Comment: Both `list.reverse` and `list.extend` are in-place operation. Try `return list1 + list2[::-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for :

```
>>> Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
>>> Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]
>>>
>>> Drews_list + Jamies_list[::-1]
['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Peter', 'Jan', 'Bobby', 'Cindy', 'Alice']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  buf = list2[:] # or list2.copy()
  buf.extend(reversed(list1))
  return buf


Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]                     
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

`extend` method for list modify current list but does not return anything, so your expression: `list3=list2.extend(list1.reverse())` assaign to `list3` value `None`

Same about `reverse`. It modifies current list, but return `None`. You can replace it with `reverse(list)` method.

Comment: You may want to create `buf` like `buf = list2[:]`, otherwise `Drews_list` (list2) will be modified as well since `list.extend` is an in-place operation

Answer (score 0):

Both `.reverse` and `.extend` return `None` and mutate list in-palce.

Try this.

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  return list1+list2[::-1]
```

And for reversing you try any of these `reversed(list2)` or `[::-1]` these methods do not mutate list in-place. Note : `reversed(list2)` gives an *iterator*

Answer (score 0):

As others have already explained, reverse() and extend() methods are in-place and return None.

**If you still want to use extend() and reverse() methods**, then you can do it like this:

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  list3 = list1[:]
  list4 = list2[:]

  list3.reverse()
  list4.extend(list3)
  return list4


Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]                     
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

If you don't mind changing list1 and list2 in the function, then you can skip copying list1 and list2 into list3 and list4 and directly do:

```
list1.reverse()
list2.extend(list1)
return list2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
    list1.reverse()
    for list in list1:
        list2.append(list)
    return list2
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  list1.reverse()
  return(list2 + list1)

Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Drews_list, Jamies_list))
```

Comment: please remember to motivate and explain your answers, please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I used the negative index to append the last element of list1 (i.e. Jamies_list) to list2 (i.e. Drews_list).

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
    for n in range(1, len(list1)+1):
        list2.append(list1[-n])
    return list2

Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]
print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
    Jamies_list.reverse()
    final_list = Drews_list + Jamies_list
    return final_list
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]
print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```